# Node.jsのインストール不要版(node.exe)でnpmを利用したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

現在、さまざまな理由から、Node.jsをインストール不要版(node.exe)で利用しています。
その状態で、npmを利用したいのですが、可能でしょうか?
また、可能な場合はどのようにすればいいでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WindowsにNode.jsを手動インストールする方法
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/eel3/20140309/1394294944

こちらにありました。